# Redesigned website: New URL structure: 301 Redirecting all old URLs

Tags: excel, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have about 5500 indexed URLs in Google on my website and will soon launch a redesigned version of it with a brand new URL structure.

Because of thousands of backlinks I want to redirect all my old urls to the new ones using htaccess 301 redirect.

The problem is, it takes forever to manually write the htaccess-rules in Excel because I have to match all the new urls with the old ones.

I.e. this is how my Excel document would be set up:

**| Old url | New url | htaccess rule |**

*/default/category/product-id/my-product* | */category/my-product/* | *301 redirect /default/category/product-id/my-product http://mydomain.com/category/my-product/*

Is there any way (software/service/tool) to match these urls based on the product name inside of the url so I don't have to do all this manually???

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of:

1. you can use a HTTP Module which reads the excel and loads in to key-value pair as old and new URL and put it in cache. Then in the BeginRequest, if the URL (old url) is found in the key, do response.redirect to new page. You can add 301 header here which will make sure the browser gets message that this is permanently redirected.
   Check [CodeProject Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2538/URL-Rewriting-with-ASP-NET)
2. If all your old and new url has got some pattern you can your IIS ReWrite module and use RegEx to create rule for the redirect.
   Check [IIS ReWrite Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Hope that helps.
Milind

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your old URLs are all in the format `/default/category/product-id/my-product`, then you can use formulas to get the next 2 cells

in **B1**, the new URL is construncted using `/category/ and the text after the 4th`/`:

```
="/category/"&MID(A1,FIND("/",A1,FIND("/",A1,FIND("/",A1,2)+1)+1)+1,99)&"/"
```

in **C1**, we can use those 2 values to construct the new redirect:

```
="301 redirect "&A1&" http://mydomain.com"&B1
```